# Dynamic sql invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have below anonymous block and here before execute immediate str string is failing due to invalid relational operator error.

not getting why.

```
SET SERVEROUT ON ;

DECLARE
   SRCE_SB_CATGRY_ID   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   FOR i
      IN (SELECT ISO_CNTRY_ID, X.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM iso_cntry I,
                 (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
                    FROM ALL_tab_cols@suplr_md_qa2
                   WHERE     table_name = 'TEMP_ARIBA'
                         AND COLUMN_NAME != 'SSC_ID') x
           WHERE ISO_CNTRY_DESC_TXT LIKE '' || COLUMN_NAME || '%')
   LOOP
      DECLARE
         str1   VARCHAR2 (10000)
            :=    ' SELECT DISTINCT ssc_id  '
               || ' FROM stddata_suplr.temp_ariba@suplr_md_qa2 '
               || ' WHERE '
               || ' '
               || i.column_name
               || ' = ''Y'' ';
         x      SYS_REFCURSOR;
      BEGIN
         OPEN x FOR str1;

         LOOP
            FETCH x INTO SRCE_SB_CATGRY_ID;

            EXIT WHEN x%NOTFOUND;



            NULL;
         END LOOP;
      END;
   END LOOP;

   END;
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem. One possibility is that one of your column names has characters that require it to be enclosed in double-quotes.  I suggest you add `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(str1)` before opening the cursor, so you can see exactly what SQL you are trying to execute.

Comment: Hi Dave,  Many thanks for your response on this , i already did that which you are suggesting , but no result , i executed the same using execute immediate but same error .

Comment: Hi Belayer , its throwing invalid relational operator , when i am passing hardcoded value instead of i.column_name in str then its working , but not working with i.column_name , i placed this string in dbms_output , and all generated statements are valid ...

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the declare section twice in anonymous block.

Try this:

```
SET SERVEROUT ON ;

DECLARE
   SRCE_SB_CATGRY_ID   VARCHAR2 (1000);
   str1   VARCHAR2 (10000);
   x      SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   FOR i
      IN (SELECT ISO_CNTRY_ID, X.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM iso_cntry I,
                 (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
                    FROM ALL_tab_cols@suplr_md_qa2
                   WHERE     table_name = 'TEMP_ARIBA'
                         AND COLUMN_NAME != 'SSC_ID') x
           WHERE ISO_CNTRY_DESC_TXT LIKE '' || COLUMN_NAME || '%')
   LOOP
         str1 :=    ' SELECT DISTINCT ssc_id  '
               || ' FROM stddata_suplr.temp_ariba@suplr_md_qa2 '
               || ' WHERE '
               || ' '
               || i.column_name
               || ' = ''Y'' ';
         
         OPEN x FOR str1;

         LOOP
            FETCH x INTO SRCE_SB_CATGRY_ID;

            EXIT WHEN x%NOTFOUND;



            NULL;
         END LOOP;
      END;
   END LOOP;

   END;
```

Please manage the logic according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi Tejas , Thanks for your suggestion , but its stil showing the same error.

Comment: Remove everything except str1 assignment and check if there is an error in dynamic query itself.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the driving looks wrong:

```
WHERE ISO_CNTRY_DESC_TXT LIKE '' || COLUMN_NAME || '%'
```

Try it without concatenating the leading quote:

```
WHERE ISO_CNTRY_DESC_TXT LIKE COLUMN_NAME || '%'
```

Comment: Hi Apc , placed your suggestion in the script , not working still throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your suggestions. It was a data error for one of the iso_cntry_id . I filtered it in my where clause and it's working fine now.

Changes which I made in first loop

```
FOR i
      IN (SELECT ISO_CNTRY_ID, X.COLUMN_NAME
            FROM iso_cntry I,
                 (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME
                    FROM ALL_tab_cols@suplr_md_qa2
                   WHERE table_name = 'TEMP_ARIBA') x
           WHERE     ISO_CNTRY_DESC_TXT LIKE '' || COLUMN_NAME || '%'
                 AND i.ISO_CNTRY_ID != 18)
   LOOP
```

best regards,
Vijay